# Extracting dates with regex in Datastudio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have data coming in with the format: `stuff_01.03.21-03.05.21`

The first date is start the second is end so I figured I could pull them out into their own columns. I know I could just do a left() but i would like to do this with a regex_extract().

I have tried: "_((\d{2}\.){2}\d{2})-" which works on regex101.com.
I have tried it as both `\\d` and `\d`. I have tried escaping the "-".

I can get it to work `_(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d)-`

Is there something with re2 syntax that is really limiting on regex expressions?

Answer (score 1):

The regex string has to start with `r"` otherwise `\d` is not allowed. This shall do the job. However, `%d` and `%m` may need to be switched:

```
parse_date("%d.%m.%Y",
REGEXP_EXTRACT("stuff_01.03.21-03.05.21",r"_(\d\d\.\d\d.\d*)-") )
```

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10496674